# Liferay sitemap.xml is redirecting to the login page

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

The /sitemap.xml path on my Liferay 7.3 servers are redirecting to my login page. It's preventing Google from being able to access it.

If you want to see the behavior the url is https://511nyrideshare.org/sitemap.xml

The servers are Liferay CE 7.3 GA7.  The default site uses a custom theme, based on the classic theme.  It has a virtual host (511nyrideshare.org) but that shouldn't be an issue as Liferay does too.  I do wonder about the virtual host though because my local development server does not have an issue.

I've looked through the settings, the properties files, etc. and can find nothing that would account for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as our SEO folk are quite agitated about it.

Comment: Add details how you enabled the sitemap xml in the portal

Comment: Great question.  The answer is that I didn't do anything to enable it.  It was created automatically.  My reading led me to believe that was the case, and the "control" over it comes from the page setting that determines if a page is included or not (they are included by default).  Once I have authenticated, the sitemap seems to be accurate.  I just need it to be accessible without authentication.

Comment: Also, I've been trying to look through all the permissions for the site to see if there is a sitemap permission somewhere.  No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The sitemap url is given by the portal site pages settings, and it looks like a url with some stuff in querystring.

Look at this image to find the right link:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that does provide the url, but doesn't explain why the url required authentication.  Clicking the preview link takes me to https://511nyrideshare.org/sitemap.xml, which works fine at that point as I'm already authenticated.  But the whole issue is that url redirects to the login page.  The other link (Google for example) just calls the Google API and passes the sitemap url to Google.

Comment: It's odd, maybe you have altered some properties about which paths are under authentication ?

Comment: No.  Not at all.  That's what is so baffling.  Two things that may be worth mentioning are:    
1 - The servers have been through a lot of updates, originally in Liferay 5.X  
2 - The site pages are all created from an organization   
But it's hard to see how that should matter.  I will investigate #2 as that would be a fairly easy test.

Comment: Create a new site from scratch, put some pages, get the sitemap xml to verify...